# Circulant determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, circulant-matrices

Suppose that $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are $n$ distinct real numbers; is the following statement true?

There is a permutation of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$, namely $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$, such that the determinant of the following matrix is nonzero:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n\\
b_2&b_3&\cdots&b_1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
b_n&b_1&\cdots&b_{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

(Such a matrix is called a [*circulant matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).)

Comment: It seems that it is anticirculant matrix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This statement is not true, without supplementary conditions on the $a_i$'s. Indeed,
suppose the $\sum_{k=1}^na_k=0 $, whatever your permutation is the vector $[1,1,\ldots,1]^T$ is in the kernel of the circulant matrix of the $b_i$'s, and consequently, its determinant is $0$.

Comment: Better answer than mine :P

Answer (score 6):

Not in the general case. Take $a_1=-1$ and $a_2=1$. In any case the determinant will be $0$.

Comment: Your answer is true but didn't covers general case!